# view the cross compiled executable output for ARM architecture on host machine

Tags: build, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, build-process, embedded-linux

I am running ubuntu on 32-bit computer.I want to cross compile a sample program such as `hello.c` (shown below) for ARM architecture.So for this cross Compilation I installed tools through command prompt .i.e. list of  tools that I have installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi    
sudo apt-get install build-essential  
sudo apt-get install binutils-multiarch
```

and finally I compiled my source program with command

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -o hello
```

and it's compiled succesfully but when I execute no output

```
./hello
```

> **bash: ./hello: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error**

what would be the problem ?
 I knew that for cross compiler means  a process of compiling and creating executable code for a platform other than the one on which the compiler is running.Don't say because of architecture difference it's occurring.Consider in some cases if my source code has some segmentation faults or any bugs which I can fix them by executing program (viewing output) in host machine itself before sending it to target machine architecture of type ARM.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
printf("hello world\n");
}
```

Comment: For run executable which doesn't fit for your running arhitectire use virtual machine or emulator. Also, for debug common problems you may compile your executable for *host machine*, so you can run it on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use qemu emulator for arm on your host machine in order to run your test program for arm processor. this is very simple arm file syem which will run on qemu , u can use it https://github.com/kaiwan/seals